# How do I persist state data on page navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I use React and React-Router, and I have a top-level component `<App/>` that contains all the session data. Whenever I navigate to a different page, I lose the state information. How can I persist the state data across all the pages? (If that is not possible, is there a different way I should be implementing my session data?)

Comment: Are you using browserRouter or hashRouter? How are you navigating between pages? If you are navigating using react-router's link elements or pushing to its history then the state of ancestor components should be preserved.

Comment: @PhilBellamy I'm using `<NavItem/>` from react-bootstrap for links, which use their href properties to navigate to different pages.

Comment: Linking between pages using a traditional href will reload the page, hence why your state is lost. By using react-router navigation techniques (e.g. Link element) the page is not reloaded and you should find that your top-level component state persists through navigation.

Comment: @PhilBellamy Thank you! I've never seen that before, I will surely check it out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [session storage (`sessionStorage`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to store data items you want to persist across pages. This is not sent to the server and will disappear when the session is over. (You could also use `localStorage` for things you may want to persist from one visit to the next.

Comment: I like using react-router navigation better than session storage (see Phil Bellamy's comment under the original question). Doesn't session storage/local storage just defeat the purpose of lifting state in react?

Answer (score 2):

I use Redux it stores the data you want outside the components and you can connect in where ever you like.